# Probability mass function of rolling 3 dice

Tags: probability, dice

How would I calculate the pmf of rolling 3 dice, where X= number of 2's appeared? I just need one example, then I should be able to figure out the whole pmf. Thanks! :)

Um, they're 3 fair 6 sided die btw.

Or maybe if someone could help me realize the partitions of the sample space?
Yeah I think then I could take off from there..! Cool, thanks ! :)

Is it each die has 1/3 chance so 3 1/3 partitions? Hmm..?

Or maybe it doesnt have partitions? Maybe its just some sort of counting problem I'm miss reading?

Comment: Um I think its one of those weird English things where its fine either way, unlike mouse and mice.

Comment: Wait...I think I figured it out! Stand by.

Comment: So the sample space is S={NNN, NNT, NTT, TTT, TTN, TNN, NTN, TNT} if T=two present and N= twos Not present, right??

Comment: What are the partitions though? Hmm..

Comment: I think that the events should be, X  = 1 (there is only one 2 after rolling 3 die), X = 2 (2 2's) and X = 3 (3 2's). To compute the probability of each event you have to use the fact that every die is fair and 6 sided.

Comment: yeah the pmf only goes up to P(X=3)

Comment: the event is still "seeing a two"

Comment: so if you have for example 2 2's that means "true" in the same way as seeing 1 two? I'm trying to understand the events of your random variable to define the partitions.

Comment: um y buddy thinks its a counting problem, which doesn't involve partitions i don't think, but in my head S=S={NNN, NNT, NTT, TTT, TTN, TNN, NTN, TNT} if T=two present and N= twos Not present. which then I could find P(X=0)...P(X=3) if i knew the percentage of 2 being present when 3 dice are rolled.

Comment: do counting problems involve partitions?

Comment: yeah no, it asks to make X = number of 2's that appear so yeah maybe its not a partition problem..?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the problem is asking you to do, but if the set-up is that you roll a fair six-sided die three times, and you want the distribution of the number of $2$s you roll, then what you want is the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with $n = 3$ dice, $p = 1/6$ probability of getting a $2$, and $k$ is the number of $2$s.

Comment: Huh, did the syntax for links change for comments?

Comment: @Brian Tung Maybe you had a space between the closing bracket and the opening parenthesis.  On the other hand, I've had attempts to italicise text in comments sometimes appear as *unitalicised* text enclosed asterisks, so maybe the engine for rendering comments just doesn't always work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Im past this exam now, and I think I was asking the question wrong, sorry the professor does not really care about asking the question correctly, this ended up being a Binomial distribution problem.